# How do I set a breakpoint inside of atom's package?

Tags: javascript, debugging, coffeescript, atom-editor

I am trying to figure out why this atom package https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-elixirc/ misbehaves. Its author said I should set a breakpoint in some function of the package to see what's going on there. I have no idea how to do that while running atom.

Here is the comment I am talking about: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-elixirc/issues/63#issuecomment-214916262

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're in Atom, hitting `Ctrl+Alt+I` (or View -> Developer -> Toggle Developer Tools) will open developer tools. If you know Chrome dev tools, it looks the same. Then just navigate to sources, find your package and set breakpoints. From menu go to view -> Developer -> reload window (or `Alt + Ctrl + R`) to re-run, so program can hit those breakpoints.

Comment: Did you mean Ctrl+Shift+I?