# How to debug HyperLedger Composer Transaction code in Playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am using a local install of Playground on MacOS.

I was successful to create my business network, add my model file and logic to this network and create assets and participants instances.

So now I am ready to submit my first transaction, but I get an error message in the popup window as a result to my request. The message per se is not the problem (it's about some Undefined asset), my problem is I want to debug this transaction code by producing some execution traces, using old-school printf or log message.

I tried to insert `console.log(message)` instructions in my transaction code  but eventually I was not able to retrieve those logs traces (eg. using a command like `docker logs -f composer`).

Is there another way to produce logs traces? Or did I miss a config setting to defilter logs in docker logs?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Olivier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On console logging (and seeing them in the browser Developer console), see this Stack Overflow here [(hyperledger composer playground) Can you see results of console.log('something') in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177296/hyperledger-composer-playground-can-you-see-results-of-console-logsomething) (it also has a link to more info there

See here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/problems/diagnostics.html for more on logging / where to find debug logs.

As for setting checkpoint/breakpoints: These are set by the Editor tooling  In H/Composer, you can just use the embedded connector (eg such as TP functions) to try out / step through each breakpoint - for more info on VSCode -> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging and Atom -> [How do I set a breakpoint inside of atom's package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964280/how-do-i-set-a-breakpoint-inside-of-atoms-package) and I posted the link to diagnostics/logging above.

Comment: The link to https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/problems/diagnostics.html is broken

Comment: try https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/problems/diagnostics.html (we have 'latest' and 'next' now -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/problems/diagnostics.html ) - have updated the link in the answer above

Answer (score 1):

One quick way I used to insert breakpoints with debug messages, is to throw an exception using `throw new Error(...)` in the transaction method.

This shows up in the playground interface as well.